# making a single number out of all the numbers in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

lets say we have an array `var arr = [1,3,4,0];` how can I make a single number out of all the elements like so `var number = 1340;` I should be able to do operations on number. The number of elements in arr could vary

Comment: *"The number of elements in arr could vary"* Just remember what the largest representable integer value is in JS.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), and [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function to convert string to number:

```
parseInt([1,3,4,0].join('')); // 1340
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method

```js
console.log(
  [1, 3, 4, 0].reduce(function(sum, n, i) {
    return sum * 10 + n;
  })
)
```

Comment: FWIW, there is no need to pass an initial value to `.reduce` in this case.

Comment: Well, it's not wrong to pass one either, I just wanted to point it out :)